# How to exclude certain sheets from script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var exclude = ["Contractors", "All Group Bids", "About Me","Bid Summary"] // these are the sheet names I do not want 
  var groupsheets = (sheets != exclude); // I'm not sure if this is formatted properly 


  for (var i=0 ; i<groupsheets.length ; i++) 

  {out.push( [ groupsheets[i].getName() ] )}

  return out 
}
```

Get names of all sheets except for some with certain names.
[other code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713DK.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste your code, instead of having it as an image

Comment: I've added the code directly. Sorry about that, the formatting was not accepting the first time around. I also don't know a ton about code. I put this together from googling script functions to perform the small task I want. I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Goal:

Return array of sheet names not found in exclusion array.

---

#### Modified Code:

```
function sheetNames() {
  var out = [];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var exclude = ["Contractors", "All Group Bids", "About Me", "Bid Summary"];
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (exclude.indexOf(sheets[i].getName()) === -1) {
      out.push(sheets[i].getName());
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

I've looped through the array of sheets using `array.indexOf()` to compare the two. Any that return `-1` (no match), are added to array `out`.

---

#### Reference:

- [`array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thank but, when I pasted it in and saved it all of the sheet names were still output. Your process makes a lot more sense than what I was doing though.

Comment: Make sure that your `exclude` array has the exact sheet names, no extra spaces & case is perfect.

Comment: It does work when I tested it on a brand new sheet. But, it does not work on the sheet I need. All of the sheet names are correct. I also have the function below running in a different script. Would that effect it?

Comment: What are you using the function to exclude sheets for? Could you show the rest of your code?

Comment: The other code automatically changes the name of a sheet if a specific cell is updated.

Comment: I'm using exclude because I have tabs titled after specific groups. I only want to see an array of those groups and not my other tabs.

Comment: function onEdit() {
  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var oldsheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var newsheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var infosheets; {["Contractors", "All Group Bids", "About Me", "Bid Summary"]};
  
  {for (var i = 0; i < oldsheetname.length; i++) 
  if (oldsheetname == infosheets){sheet.setName(oldsheetname);}
  if (oldsheetname !== infosheets && oldsheetname !== newsheetname){sheet.setName(newsheetname);}
   } }

Comment: Sorry I couldn't format and paste it up to because, I kept getting an error message saying to make sure all of my question wasn't code

Comment: Ok - so why do you even need this function at all? You're not using it to return anything? If you're trying to exclude those sheets from your `onEdit` script you need to include the code in that script or call the function somewhere...

Comment: So to clarify because, I'm not sure if it's entirely clear... I'm using both scripts for two different purposes. They are saved as two separate codes. I need the onEdit because, after I manually duplicate a sheet I would like to have it renamed after a value in a cell on that sheet. This cell has a data validation drop down menu of a list. I click a value from the list and the sheet name changes. But you're right, the line of my "excluded items" is not serving a purpose. I could not figure out how to exclude those sheets so I did a work around to make sure my reference cell on those sheets

Comment: stays blank. I could delete that part honest. I just settled because the script's output was good enough for me. Thanks for being so patient with me.

Comment: My sheetNames script is to be used on the Bid Summary tab because, I only want certain sheets to appear in a blank column. Then I'm going to use the QUERY function to match values to columns on the rest of the sheet.

Comment: So do you want sheetNames to return a comma separated list of your sheet names?

Comment: No, I actually want it to return an array so each sheet name has its own cell in a column. So essentially the code you gave me works in theory. But, I'm not sure why I am returned all sheet names when I apply it to my file.

Comment: The function I provided does exactly that, I just tested it myself.

Comment: Yup, just updated my comment above saying that. I'll play around with it to see if I can narrow down the problem. Thanks for the the help!

Comment: Share your sheet if possible and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: There were extra spaces at the end of my sheet names that I couldn't see. It works now! Much thanks and many blessings to you!

Comment: Yeah - tends to be the case for these sorts of questions! Glad I could help.

Comment: @A.E. please remember to mark the answer as correct if the solution provided answered your question sufficiently. This is not mandatory but may help users in the future to find a solution.

Comment: Here is a more concise version using es6+ features. This isn't necessarily "better" but I always find it's easier to make mistakes working with imperative loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise version using es6+ features. This isn't necessarily "better" than https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100899/181344 but I always find it's easier to make mistakes when working with imperative loops:

```
function sheetNames() {
  let excluded = ["Contractors", "All Group Bids", "About Me", "Bid Summary"];
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()
    .filter(s => !excluded.includes(s));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bumping old thread. This didn't work for me, can you help?